# Approximation to the pth root of an integer N

Tags: elementary-number-theory, approximation

I was working on the  *Introduction to Number theory* textbook by CJ Bradley and encountered the following theorem .

If $N>0$ and $\frac{u}{v}$ is a good rational approximation to $\mathrm{N}^{\frac{1}{p}}$ , where $p$ is a positive integer, then
$$
\frac{U}{V}=\frac{u\left\{(p-1) u^{p}+(p+1) v^{p} N\right\}}{v\left\{(p+1) u^{p}+(p-1) v^{p} N\right\}}
$$
is a far better approximation, in the sense that if
$$
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{p}=N\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{N}\right) \text { and }\left|\frac{\varepsilon}{N}\right|<1,
$$
then
$$
\left(\frac{U}{V}\right)^{p}=N\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\varepsilon^{3}}{N^{3}}\right)\right) .
$$
Note that $\mathcal{O}$ means the order of the given expression

The book states that the proof is straightforward and requires only the use of the binomial theorem.
Naturally, I tried applying it but i can't seem to prove it.
A direction to work upon or a proof will suffice and will be appreciated
Thanks a lot

Comment: have you tried expanding $(U/V)^p$ in $\epsilon$?

Comment: @user619894 I don't get you. I did try raising the whole expression to the power _p_

Comment: Didn't the $O(\epsilon)$ terms cancel?

Comment: I don't think they did

Comment: First order cancels for me. Show your work and I will share.

Comment: Could you just send a small part of your solution that can give me headway?